# How safe is it to edit PHP files in Web browser via CPanel?

Tags: tls, sftp, cpanel

For some reason my Notepad++ can't connect via SFTP since yesterday so I was thinking about editing my site via CPanel file manager which has HTTPS.

I never thought about editing my site in this way, so I'm wondering if it's as safe as SFTP?

Comment: "as safe" from what? from whom?

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is as safe as SFTP if handled properly (reasonable algorithms and parameters). And of course if you use reasonable authentication method (which is not discussed here), but on this level, none of the protocols have serious flaw that it would make insecure.